# ODE solution to $x''+\omega_0^2 x = \frac{F_0}{m} cos (\omega t) , \ \ for \ \omega \neq \omega_0$ using Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am analyzing solution to the ODE 
$$x''+\omega_0^2 x = \frac{F_0}{m} cos (\omega t) , \ \ for \ \omega \neq \omega_0$$

The guess function is
$$x_p=A cos(\omega t) +B sin(\omega t)$$

I calculate the $X_p'$ and $x_p''$

$$X_p'=-A \omega \ sin(\omega t) + B \omega \ cos(\omega t) $$
$$X_p''=-A(sin(\omega t) + \omega^2 cos(\omega t) \ ) \ \ +  \ \ B( \ cos(\omega t))-\omega^2 sin(\omega t) \ )$$

inserting the $X_p'$ and $x_p''$ into the first equation and comparing to th RHS I get the following equation

$$\mathbf{A(\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)} \ cos(\omega t) + B \ (\omega_o^2 - \omega^2) sin(\omega t) + A \ sin(\omega t) + B \ cos(\omega t) = \mathbf{\frac{F_0}{m}} cos(\omega t)$$
assuming $B=0$
$$\mathbf{A(\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)} \ cos(\omega t) + \color{red}{ A \sin(\omega t) } = \mathbf{\frac{F_0}{m}} cos(\omega t)$$
 
 
Solution suggest $A=\mathbf{\frac{F_0}{m (\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)}}$ which I don't get because of the the $A \ sin (\omega t)$ term.
 
 
**Where I am making a mistake?**

Second thing suggested in the manual is equating B=0 straight away (as there is no dump term). How would we know in this case that B =0 before doing the algebra?

Comment: $X_p''$ expression is wrong.

Comment: You mixed taking derivatives with respect to $t$, and to $\omega$. In $X_p''$ you should only get terms with $\omega^2$

Comment: How would I know that it could be assumed $B=0$  in the beginning  so that $x_p=A cos(\omega t)$ would the guess?

Answer (score 1):

$$X_p'=-A \omega \ sin(\omega t) + B \omega \ cos(\omega t) $$
$$X_p''=-A  \omega^2 cos(\omega t) -B \omega^2 sin(\omega t) $$

$$\mathbf{A(\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)} \ cos(\omega t) + B \ (\omega_o^2 - \omega^2) sin(\omega t)  = \mathbf{\frac{F_0}{m}} cos(\omega t)$$
assuming $B=0$
$$\mathbf{A(\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)} \ cos(\omega t) = \mathbf{\frac{F_0}{m}} cos(\omega t)$$

$$A=\frac{F_0}{m (\omega_o^2 - \omega^2)}$$